# How to connect my domain to my FTP server?

Tags: dns, ftp, subdomain, synology, google-cloud-dns

I have an FTP server running on a local synology server. It has an external IP address to which I can connect to using an FTP client on port 21. I'm wondering if there is a way to access this FTP server using my domain (ex. ftp.mydomain.com or something similar). The DNS for my domain is managed on Google Cloud DNS.

How do I get started with achieving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create [private](https://cloud.google.com/dns/zones/#creating_private_zones) or [public](https://cloud.google.com/dns/zones/#creating_public_zones) zone at Google Cloud DNS (depends on your needs) and that's all. In case you need public zone - you should [register domain name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_registration) at first and then use exactly the same NS records you'll get at Google Cloud DNS as DNS servers for your domain at  registrar's control panel. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/best-practices-dns#best_practices_for_private_zones) you can find best practices for private zones. After creating dns zone for your domain you should create [`A record`](https://kb.pressable.com/article/dns-record-types-explained/) for your ftp.

If you need more specific information - please update your question.